# Kosher Food in Heathrow airport

Tags: transit, food-and-drink, lhr, religion, dietary-restrictions

I have a 4.5 hr connection in Heathrow Terminal 5 (US Passport holder) and would like to know if there is kosher food available for sale in the airport, i would go to a diffrent terminal if thats where its available

Comment: What kind of kosher food? Anything that doesn't contain pork and doesn't mix milk with meat? Or food that's officially stamped by a Rabbi?

Comment: @JonathanReez, if someone is asking it always means rabbinic supervision, for other purposes vegetarian is good enough and easily available in most places.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[According to Kosher Today](http://www.koshertoday.com/heathrow-latest-airport-offer-travelers-kosher-food/), at least as of 2015, there are kosher sandwiches and wraps at the [WHSmith](http://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/shops-a-z/whsmith) stores in terminals 2, 3, 4, and 5. There's a phone number on that page, and it might be helpful to call ahead and confirm.

Failing that, [The Heathrow website](http://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/restaurants-a-z/special-dietary-options) says that kosher food is available at [Caffe Nero](http://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/restaurants-a-z/caff%C3%A8-nero). In Terminal 5, that restaurant is located in the arrivals area, meaning that you would have to go through UK Immigration to access it. There are also locations post-security in other terminals, but you cannot simply just go there unless you have a flight from those terminals. They will [allow you to change terminals for expensive shopping trips](http://boutique.heathrow.com/terminal-transfer), and it's possible that they could offer you the same service if you inquire in advance, should you not want to cross the UK border. However, WHSmith in T5 is post-security and likely your best bet.

[The website of Hermolis](http://www.hermolis.com/sandwiches.php), the kosher caterer they use, confirms the above.

There are also [reports](http://forums.dansdeals.com/index.php?topic=27318.0) from a few years ago that they keep a supply of frozen kosher meals on hand at the British Airways lounge, should you have access to that facility. That forum thread has some anecdotal experience that would be useful to read.

Since these meals are brought in prepackaged by an outside company, it would be a good idea to bring something with you, in case they are unavailable.

Comment: *Fascinating*. Money literally gets you everywhere.

Comment: @chx I've been curious about how much you could abuse that service, since, after all, you could simply go look at some expensive handbags and then decide not to buy. I think it may come with a personal shopper though, so you'd have to figure out how to ditch them. Anyway, if you ever have a lot of time to kill at Heathrow, I'd be curious how it all works.

Comment: @ZachLipton I don't think you can do that.  That website clearly states: _This service is restricted to passengers making purchases of £250 or more._ That is, you must spend at least £250 on shopping. Plus you need to go to a specific retailer, because, again from the same website, _We are not able to transfer passengers to retailers that have stores in every terminal._

Answer (score 9):

I’m at Heathrow now (September 2019). There are parve falafel wraps and also chicken wraps in the refrigerator section of the WH Smith that is on the security checkpoint level (after security), but not the WH Smith down on the level by the gates.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. It might help if you add the terminal number, since every terminal is different.

Answer (score 3):

[image: LHR terminal 2 WH Smith upper level]

LHR terminal 2 WH Smith upper level